# How do I Find an object up the list I am iterating through

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I am iterating through a List of objects of Type "prvEmployeeIncident".

The object has the following properties:

```
public DateTime DateOfIncident { get; set; }
public bool IsCountedAsAPoint; 
public decimal OriginalPointValue;
public bool IsFirstInCollection { get; set; }
public bool IsLastInCollection { get; set; }
public int PositionInCollection { get; set; }
public int DaysUntilNextPoint { get; set; }
public DateTime DateDroppedBySystem { get; set; }
public bool IsGoodBehaviorObject { get; set; }
```

My List is sorted by the DateOfIncident property.  I would like to find the next object **up** the list where IsCounted == true and change it to IsCounted = false.

One question:

1) How do I find this object up the list ?

Comment: Probably the next item that matches.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use LINQ [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx):

```
var nextObject = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsCountedAsAPoint);

if (nextObject != null) 
    nextObject.IsCountedAsAPoint = false;
```

Comment: Can I use a lambda on a collection that I am already in the middle of iterating through ?

Comment: @user1073912: it should not since it is not better performance, but please could you post your code for more understanding?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly this can be solved with a simple foreach loop. I don't exactly understand your emphasis on "up" as you don't really move up a list, you traverse it. Anyways, the following code snippet finds the first Incident where IsCounted is true and changes it to false. If you're starting from a given position change the for each loop to a for loop and start at `i = currentIndex` with the exit condition being `i < MyList.Count`. Leave the break statement to ensure you only modify one Incident object.

```
  foreach (prvEmployeeIncident inc in MyList)
  {
       if (inc.IsCountedAsAPoint)
       {
          inc.IsCountedAsAPoint = false;
          break;
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`List(T).FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eb596wz.aspx) to search up the list.

Example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo() { }

    public Foo(int item)
    {
        Item = item;
    }

    public int Item { get; set; }
}

var foos = new List<Foo>
                {
                    new Foo(1),
                    new Foo(2),
                    new Foo(3),
                    new Foo(4),
                    new Foo(5),
                    new Foo(6)
                };

foreach (var foo in foos)
{
    if(foo.Item == 3)
    {
        var startIndex = foos.IndexOf(foo) + 1;
        var matchedFooIndex = foos.FindIndex(startIndex, f => f.Item % 3 == 0);
        if(matchedFooIndex >= startIndex) // Make sure we found a match
            foos[matchedFooIndex].Item = 10;
    }
}
```

[image: New collection]

Just be sure you do not modify the list itself since that will throw an exception.